# Is it possible to remove/override an existing coercion?

Tags: coq, coercion

I have imported a Coq module which defines a coercion, but it does not fit my needs.  Is there any way to remove or (locally) override it?

To be specific, say the module I imported defines a coercion

`Coercion bool_to_nat (b:bool) := match b with true => 1 | false => 0 end.`

but I want to use the opposite in my code

`Local Coercion bool_to_nat' (b:bool) := match b with true => 0 | false => 1 end.`

Coq gives a warning `Ambiguous paths: [bool_to_nat'] : bool >-> nat` and simply ignores my definition (can be checked by `Goal false + 1 = true. reflexivity. Qed.`  Is it possible to convince Coq to respect my choice, at least locally in this file?

It would be a plus to be able to explicitly manipulate coercions after they are declared, like how one is able to manipulate hint databases.  Are there such commands?

Comment: I think it is not possible at the moment. Perhaps you could open an [issue](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues) about this?

Comment: @AntonTrunov I opened an issue here: https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/9275

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Coq 8.15 you can import everything except coercions:

```
Import -(coercions) ModuleName.
```

Cf. the manual for [import categories](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/language/core/modules.html#grammar-token-import_categories).